# Getting individual objects in json request Body in key, value format

Tags: java, json

Please help the beginner.

When sending a request to the requestBody json I get:

```
key: "{
  "grant_type" : "client_credentials",
  "client_id" : "OC_CLIENT_ID",
  "client_secret" : "OC_CLIENT_SECRET"
}"
value: ""
```

and it is required that the requestBody looks like this

```
{
  key:"grant_type" 
  value: "client_credentials"
}
{
  key:"client_id" 
  value: "OC_CLIENT_ID"
}
{
  key:"client_secret" 
  value: "OC_CLIENT_SECRET"
}
```

The server sent for some reason not a set of parameters, but simply stuck json into the name of the first parameter.

The code is:

```
@Path("/")
public interface OAuth2RequestService {
    @POST
    AccessTokenRecord create(@HeaderParam(value = "Content-type") String type,
                             @FormParam(value = "grant_type") String grantType,
                             @FormParam(value = "client_id") String clientId,
                             @FormParam(value = "client_secret") String clientSecret);
}

@Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public OAuth2Interceptor getAccessTokenInterceptor(Account account,
                                                       Boolean isGeneralEpaService) {
        if (openAmIsEnabled(account)) {
            final FeignOptions<OAuth2RequestService> options =
                    new FeignOptions<>(getAccessTokenUrl(account, isGeneralEpaService));
            final AccessTokenRecord accessTokenRecord = workerRestService(options)
                    .create(HEADER_TYPE, CLIENT_CREDENTIALS, getClientId(isGeneralEpaService),
                            getClientSecret(isGeneralEpaService));
            logger.infof("OAuth2 access token retrieval succeeded.");
            return new OAuth2Interceptor(accessTokenRecord);
        }
        final AccessTokenRecord accessTokenRecord = new AccessTokenRecord();
        accessTokenRecord.setAccessToken(getOsDefaultAccessToken(account));
        accessTokenRecord.setTokenType(TOKEN_TYPE);
        return new OAuth2Interceptor(accessTokenRecord);
    }
private OAuth2RequestService workerRestService(
        final FeignOptions<OAuth2RequestService> options) {
    final Request.Options requestOptions =
            new Request.Options(options.getConnectionTimeOut(), options.getReadTimeOut());
    return Feign.builder().options(requestOptions).client(new OkHttpClient())
            .contract(new JAXRSContract()).encoder(new JacksonEncoder())
            .decoder(new JacksonDecoder()).decode404()
            .target(OAuth2RequestService.class, options.getHostUrl());
}
```

I have tried several options with `@QueueParam @FormParam`

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please indicate where you are stuck and show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include those details ?